# Remote accessing of elasticsearch5?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am working with elastic search 5 and I setup it on my local network.
Now I need t access through remote, I had changed my configuration as follows but it not worked.

```
network.host: 0.0.0.0
```

Any suggestion, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution to my problem.

I have added following configuration to yml file

```
http.host: myIpAddress
```

Reference available [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-access-remotely-to-elasticsearch-5/65211/2)

Thank you.